# Java logging question. It doesn't work out. Cannot find the reason

Tags: java, logging

Error here?
It doesn't work out and I cannot get the reason :(

```java
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "test.dat";
        Logger.getGlobal().info(filename+"opened file");

    }

}
```

Comment: In your question you haven't defined [what you expect to happen](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Defining that helps provide a good answer.  By default your code will generate a message from the global logger and print to the console handler of the root logger.  There is no code you defined to open a file unless you specified it in the logger configuration not included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

to

```
java.util.logging.Logger
```

or there will be no output in neither console nor log file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this import - `import java.util.logging.FileHandler;`

Then add file handler before logging info:

```
FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler("test.dat", true);        
Logger.getGlobal().addHandler(fileHandler);
```